# Front End Dev in Asp.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, frontend

So I just started working in a new environment. Its a Microsoft Shop that uses ASP.NET MVC 4 on most of their projects. I'm coming from a mac/linux/open source environment where I worked on the front-end exclusively.

I'm having a hard time working in this .Net environment for a few reasons, one being that ASP.NET MVC is completely new to me. I also feel like to effectively fix issues I need to have some full stack skills too.

I've looked around for some ASP.NET MVC books but most of them expect you to know a bit of C#. I have no interest in learning C# though. What can I do to help myself work more effectively in this environment?

Comment: You should strive to learn about the environment you are in whether or not you are doing "front-end".  Would you expect to not know a line of PHP for PHP frontend development?  No Ruby for Ruby dev, etc.  Unless you are only creating static HTML files, then yes, you will need to learn Razor syntax, some C#, and understand what a model is.  Work a tutorial...see what happens.  You could be surprised.

Comment: If you want to be ASP.NET front-end developer you have to learn C# first. There is no chance to skip this step. But in your case basics might be enough.

Answer (score 11):

**Firstly**, Your best resources are the people around you. They understand not just the framework but they way the business is using it. In any framework there is a myriad of ways to do something, it may not be the best way, but its they way they have chosen.

Books are great if you want to get a general understanding before you start, but once you are in there the fastest way to get into it is use the people around you. As questions, lots of questions, make sure they know you aren't incompetent, just that you want to learn.

**Secondly**, if you don't want to learn C# your in for some trouble, ASP.NET (even doing front end only) will require knowledge of C#. the pages are `.cshtml` for a reason because they amalgamate C# and HTML in one.

Depending on how deep you are required to go, you may need to write up some controller functionality, meaning you will need to understand C# fully. If you are solely doing `.cshtml` pages then a limited subset of C# should suffice. However the more you know the easier you will find it in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

C# is one of the language which you can use to drive ASP.Net MVC Technology. You can opt for other languages like VB.Net also. In my answer, I am going to say some options other than C#, that is build your server with JavaScript, render you page with JavaScript framework.

To learn ASP.Net MVC - [Pro ASP.Net MVC 4](http://www.apress.com/9781430242369), [ASP.Net MVC 4 in Action](http://www.manning.com/palermo3/)

If you do not want to learn C#, then you can build applications only with HTML, CSS and JQuery. So the complete middle tier would be of JavaScript. There are JavaScript Servers like Node.js. You can learn Node.js from this book - [Node.js in Action](http://www.manning.com/cantelon/).

Instead of using Razor to render pages in ASP.Net MVC, you can use plain HTML and CSS and using JQuery frameworks like [KnockOutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/), [AngularJs](http://www.amazon.in/AngularJS-Brad-Green/dp/1449344852?tag=googinhydr2622-21) etc. Before you get on to this JavaScript frameworks, its better you refresh/learn your knowledge in JQuery thorugh [JQuery in Action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/).

Having your frontend and middle tier both in JavaScript, removes the complete dependency of ASP.Net MVC and C#. At the same time, even if you Middle Tier (Server) is built with IIS and ASP.Net MVC combination, you can still use JavaScript frameworks to render frontend.

As mentioned above if you want to get started with Middle tier in ASP.Net + IIS combination, C# must be learned (definitely it will not demand in-depth knowledge, but you should get some experiences in concepts like LINQ etc.,). To learn C#, get this book - [C# 4.0 Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672336901).

As you just got started, you can go with ASP.Net MVC + C# combination, and then slowly look into other options as I mentioned above.